# Generate and combine FOR XML AUTO

Tags: sql-server, xml

I'm generating xml from tables with queries like this

```
 SELECT * 
   FROM Rp 
FOR XML AUTO

 SELECT * 
   FROM Ind 
FOR XML AUTO
```

I would like to combine a bunch of these and generate a single xml file probably something I can automate in VS2010

any pointers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found it, this works

```
Select 
   ( SELECT * FROM Rp FOR XML AUTO, TYPE)
,
   ( SELECT * FROM Ind FOR XML AUTO, TYPE)

  FOR XML PATH('Root')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    SELECT ID,SUBSTRING(
    (
    SELECT ',' + [Name]
    FROM MyTable C
    WHERE P.ID=C.ID
    ORDER BY [Name]
    FOR XML PATH('')
    ),2,2000) as [Name]

FROM MyTable P
GROUP BY ID
```

Answer (score -1):

combine how?
you could simply use UNION

```
SELECT * FROM Rp  
FOR XML AUTO 
UNION 
SELECT * FROM Ind  
FOR XML AUTO
```

Comment: I get this error running this query it seems you can't do union on FOR XML AUTO selects

Comment: This is the error "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'UNION'" pressed enter too soon :)

Comment: also to answer your question about how I want to get all of the data from each of the tables (Rp, Ind and several others) but I want to combine all the resultant xml fragments into one xml